# How does this code use only updates into core data?

Tags: ios, core-data

This is a SyncEngine from an RW tutorial.  I need help understanding how only UPDATED records from the web are fetched and processed into Core Data.

```
- (void)processJSONDataRecordsIntoCoreData {
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [[SDCoreDataController sharedInstance] backgroundManagedObjectContext];
    // Iterate over all registered classes --- CHECK!
    for (NSString *className in self.registeredClassesToSync) {
        if (![self initialSyncComplete]) { 
            NSDictionary *JSONDictionary = [self JSONDictionaryForClassWithName:className];
            NSArray *records = [JSONDictionary objectForKey:@"results"];
            for (NSDictionary *record in records) {
                [self newManagedObjectWithClassName:className forRecord:record];
            }
        } else {
            NSArray *downloadedRecords = [self JSONDataRecordsForClass:className sortedByKey:@"objectId"];
            if ([downloadedRecords lastObject]) {
                 NSArray *storedRecords = [self managedObjectsForClass:className sortedByKey:@"objectId" usingArrayOfIds:[downloadedRecords valueForKey:@"objectId"] inArrayOfIds:YES];
                int currentIndex = 0;
                //if dl count is < current index, there is an updated object dl from the web
                for (NSDictionary *record in downloadedRecords) {
                    NSManagedObject *storedManagedObject = nil;
                    //Quick check to see if they indeed match, if they do, update the stored object with remote service objects
                    if ([storedRecords count] > currentIndex) {
                        storedManagedObject = [storedRecords objectAtIndex:currentIndex];
                    }
                    //Othwerwise its a new object and you need to create a new NSManagedObject to represent it in CDdb
                    if ([[storedManagedObject valueForKey:@"objectId"] isEqualToString:[record valueForKey:@"objectId"]]) {
                        [self updateManagedObject:[storedRecords objectAtIndex:currentIndex] withRecord:record];
                    } else {
                        [self newManagedObjectWithClassName:className forRecord:record];
                    }
                    currentIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
        // After all NSMO are created in your context, save it!
        [managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
            NSError *error = nil;
            if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Unable to save context for class %@", className);
            }
        }];
        // Cleanup time
        [self deleteJSONDataRecordsForClassWithName:className];
        [self executeSyncCompletedOperations];
    }

   [self downloadDataForRegisteredObjects:NO];
}
```

From what I understand, on the first or initial sync, it fetches JSONDictionaryForClassWithName which reads the downloaded data from disk and creates a newManagedObjectWithClassName.

My confusion is in the update else block.  downloadedRecords is populated from JSONDataRecordsForClass which simply calls JSONDictionaryForClassWithName.  Then it checks to see if there is at least 1 object in that array.  If there is it does this:

```
NSArray *storedRecords = [self managedObjectsForClass:className sortedByKey:@"objectId" usingArrayOfIds:[downloadedRecords valueForKey:@"objectId"] inArrayOfIds:YES];
```

This fetches all managedObjectsForClass:sortedByKey which is below:

```
- (NSArray *)managedObjectsForClass:(NSString *)className sortedByKey:(NSString *)key usingArrayOfIds:(NSArray *)idArray inArrayOfIds:(BOOL)inIds {
    __block NSArray *results = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [[SDCoreDataController sharedInstance] backgroundManagedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:className];
    NSPredicate *predicate;
    if (inIds) {
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"objectId IN %@", idArray];
    } else {
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (objectId IN %@)", idArray];
    }

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:
                                      [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"objectId" ascending:YES]]];
    [managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    }];

    return results;
}
```

The next bit which compares the [storedRecords count] > currentIndex is confusing.  Can someone please explain this?  I think my confusion lies in what the managedObjectsForClass method does with the usingArraysOfIds & inArrayOfIds.

I would expect that at some point it gets the the updatedAt field from the downloaded records and compares it to the updatedAt field of the CoreData fetched records.

Answer (score 0):

This function is processing the stored JSON.  The actual remote fetching and updateAt checking happens in `downloadDataForRegisteredObjects` and `mostRecentUpdatedAtDateForEntityWithName`.

`[storedRecords count] > currentIndex` is a bit crazy.  Although in defense of the original programmer, writing any decent syncengine will quickly make you go googoo.  Basically he needs to work out which records are existing and which ones are new and update the local data store accordingly, that's all.

---

I had another look and this code is actually horribly broken.  It will only works if either you have the same records both locally and remotely.  Or if the new objects have an objectId that sort-wise comes after the last object the local store has.  Which is not the case with Parse objectId's.

If you are testing with just one device this works because new objects will be inserted locally before being pushed to the server. Therefor you will always have the same amount of records.  If additional records get inserted any other way, this code will do weird things.

Comment: that's exactly what I want to understand why it works, the "working out which records are existing and which ones are new".  And believe me, I've been working to understand this code and I appreciate the complexity! :). Could you explain how the existing and new ones works?